# react native debugger gives remote error

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I am running VS code tool and run it on windows, after creating a sample project `react-native init testProject`

I try to debug the application by debugging it. i attached an android configuration:

```
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Debug Android",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
        "type": "reactnative",
        "request": "launch",
        "platform": "android",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
    },
```

am having an issue to debug and run the app, i spent hours to try to figure it out without success, i downgrade the cli to 1.0, adb kill-server but no success, every time i have the error:
[image]

I am running out of idea, what can i do more ?

Thanks

Comment: Where did you apply that Android configuration?

Comment: Hi Sebastian: in the launch.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah after hours of searching, trial and errors, reinstalling the cli, react native, upgrading without success....

I tried to disable the avast antivirus and unbelievable, the error is coming from that !